# Can MYSQL CASE expression running well with the same WHEN condition?

Tags: mysql

as you see:

```
UPDATE activity
SET number = CASE
WHEN aid = 45 THEN
    number + 1 
WHEN aid = 43 THEN
    number + 1 
END
WHERE
    aid IN (45, 43)
```

this queries is running well.
but:

```
UPDATE activity
SET number = CASE
WHEN aid = 45 THEN
    number + 1 
WHEN aid = 43 THEN
    number + 1 
WHEN aid = 45 THEN
    number + 3
WHEN aid = 49 THEN
    number + 1
END
WHERE
    aid IN (45, 43,49)
```

there is something wrong with the query.the second "WHEN aid=45..." is not work.The result is when aid=45 the number increase 1,but i want the number increase 4.

thanks for the answer.but i think my questions are described so simple.So,may be i should describe it in detailed.
There are my PHP code which to update the different activity's number.The aid is primary key.

```
/*
$aids is an array which the key is the activity's primary key and the 
value is the activity's number.
example $aids = array('45'=>4,'43'=>1...)
In the array,i combine all the same aid to one element.so one aid can 
not be used twice by the case expression.And  all the number are total
number.
*/
$sql = 'update huodong_activity set applynumber = case ';
$aids_str = implode(',',array_keys($aids)); 
foreach($aids as $k=>$v){
      $sql .= sprintf(' when aid = %d then applynumber-%d',$k,$v);
}
$sql .= ' END WHERE aid IN ('.$aids_str.') ';
$db->query($sql);
```

my question is :

1.I really don't know why case expression doesn't work by "aid=45" used twice or more ?

2.I don't know how many rows could be updated by the "update case expression" or any limits ?

Comment: Why do you have the `CASE` `WHEN aid = 45` twice?

Comment: Then why not make it as `number + 4` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second version won't work as the case expression will match the first 45 and then stop. Just remove the `WHEN aid = 45 THEN number + 1` and change the second to `WHEN aid = 45 THEN number + 4` if you want to increase it by 4 like this:

```
UPDATE activity
SET number = CASE
WHEN aid IN (43, 49) THEN
    number + 1 
WHEN aid = 45 THEN
    number + 4
END
WHERE
    aid IN (45, 43, 49)
```

Comment: `aid = 43 OR aid = 49 ` can be shortened to  `aid IN(43, 49)` as well)

Comment: By the way, as `aid IN (45, 43, 49)` you can change query to `UPDATE activity
SET number = number + (CASE
WHEN aid = 45 THEN
    4
ELSE 1
END)
WHERE
    aid IN (45, 43, 49)`

Comment: @notulysses Yes indeed, but maybe at the loss of clarity. If the OP were to remove the where condition the query would not have the expected outcome any longer so I think it might be better to be explicit.

Comment: Yeah, but you can post it with a caveat using, maybe, an `IF` to show that it can be shortened even more in this particular case : `UPDATE activity SET number = number + IF(aid = 45, 4, 1) WHERE aid IN (45, 43, 49)`

Comment: @jpw  thanks for your answer.the queries is a part of my all queries.In fact,i want to update the number by different condition.I think ,there are more than 1000 rows will be updated,is any limit in my queries?

Comment: @zerodeng There's no limit to how many rows you can update other than maybe those imposed by available memory and time, but updating a 1000 rows should never be any problem.